# Magento OnePageCheckout | Adjust layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, onepage-checkout, xml, newsletter

I want to move the **Ebizmarts_MageMonkey_Block_Checkout_Subscribe** block to be under **Mage_Checkout_Block_Agreements**. What would be the best way to approach it?

Here is a screen shot of current layout:

[image]

**Please let me know if you need anymore information!**

Comment: When you say "under" you mean "inside"? Or literally "under"?

Comment: To be fair, any would do me good. I just need to move this block to be below the other one...

Answer (score 1):

As this is a customization over MageMonkey module, I'd make the change in his layout (not tested, just an idea)

**app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/layout/magemonkey.xml**

And then, change

```
<!-- Checkout -->
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
               template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml">
            <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

For this

```
<!-- Checkout -->
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.agreements">
        <block type="monkey/checkout_subscribe" name="magemonkey.subscribe"
               template="magemonkey/checkout/subscribe.phtml" output="toHtml">
            <block type="monkey/signup" name="left.monkeysignup" template="magemonkey/lists.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```

Basically, there are 2 changes:

1. Change reference block to inject content from **checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after** to your desired one: **checkout.onepage.agreements**
2. We need to add **output="toHtml"** code to print the block's output, as new parent block won't do that by default (previous one did it, as it has type = `core/text_list`)

Comment: Hi @RaulSanchez! Thank you for your interest. The above completely removed the block from "Review" section.

Comment: Thank for directing me anyway. I feel like I'm a step closer. Changing the reference to **checkout.onepage.review.info.items.before** worked and the block moved so I'm guessing it's something wrong with the `output="toHtml"` but not quiet sure what.

Comment: output="toHtml" didn't work, however, adding this: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('magemonkey.subscribe') ?>` to agreements.phtml file worked for me :)

Comment: Nice... output parameter was a try to avoid editing the agreements template

Comment: I got there finally :D Update your answer with this and I will accept it :)

Comment: No need to update, I am glad if it helped ;) Feel free to give some upvote or write your own answer & accept that as the valid one